# Game Center leaderboards sometimes fail to load

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center

I've noticed that sometimes when a user tries to view a GameCenter leaderboard in my app they get a blank white screen with the error "unable to load data due to network connectivity issues or errors". This happens when all other connectivity is fine (i.e.: on wifi, web pages load, email load etc). It happens maybe 20% of the time. I'm not sure if I might be doing something wrong or if Game Center is just weird like that. It definitely fails to load more often than an HTTP request and does not seem to retry. Closing the leaderboards and re-opening usually fixes it, but I have numerous complains about this from my users so I just thought I'd ask here to see if it is a known issue. Thanks.

This is how I show my leaderboards

```
- (void)showLeaderboard:(NSString *)leaderboard
{
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    gameCenterController.leaderboardIdentifier=leaderboard;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
    isShowingHighScores=TRUE;
}
```

Where leaderboard is the identifier string for the leaderboard they clicked on.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a different user.
Pehaps the user was sending spam to CG and it blocked it. A different user worked for me.

Comment: It's not a problem with a user being banned. I'm the developer and I obviously haven't banned myself.